# Integral involving multiple Bessel functions.

Tags: improper-integrals, bessel-functions

I am trying to see if there are any known solutions to integrals of the following form, any help would be appreciated:

$$\int_0^\infty xJ_{\nu+1}(ax)J_{\nu}(bx)\sin(cx)dx.$$

I've dug through a few fairly comprehensive tables, but have yet to find anything.

Comment: Your integral is probably divergent since the integrand behaves like the product of two cosines and a sine for large $x$ (cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.7.E8). If the power of $x$ was a bit less than $1$, $6.578/1.$ in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik would work.

Comment: Please define what Bessel functions are.

Comment: Gradshteyn and Ryzhik 6.626/1 (7th Edition) appears useful, but there may be issues of convergence.